# How to render collections of forms

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I have problem with rendering forms in Twig. I'm trying to embed a collection of forms. When I render the collection, it is not shown, while it is shown the name of form. The aim was to make the forms with an add button to add at runtime the form for each element of the collection. I get a look to the Symfony Docs and I think I followed it step by step.

This is my controller:

```
function new_resultAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $test = $em->getRepository('LadelaOdeskTesterBundle:Test')->find($id);
    $categories =  
      $em->getRepository('LadelaOdeskTesterBundle:Category')->findByTest($test);
    if (!$test) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Test entity.');
    } 

    $resultCategory = new Category();


    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType() , $resultCategory);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($resultCategory);                
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->setFlash('success', 'New result Categories were 
          saved!');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('questions', array(
                'id' => $resultCategory->getId(),
            )));
        }
    }                 
  return array(
        'test' => $test,
        'categories' =>$categories,

        'form' => $form->createView(), 


      );

}
```

My forms:

```
 class ResultCategoryType extends AbstractType
    {
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder->add('value', 'integer');
    $builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'Ladela\OdeskTesterBundle\Entity\Category',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) { return 
     $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC'); },
             'property' => 'name' ,
               'expanded' => false ,
               'multiple' => false , ));


 }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Ladela\OdeskTesterBundle\Entity\ResultCategory'
    ));
  }

  public function getName()
{
    return 'ResultCategory';
}
 }

 class CategoryType extends AbstractType
 {
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('resultCategories','collection', array(
            'type' => new ResultCategoryType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype' => true,

        ))
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Ladela\OdeskTesterBundle\Entity\Category'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'category';
}
```

}

And my twig file:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('questions',{'id': test.id })  }}" {{   
  form_enctype(form) }} >    

  <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ 
  form_widget(form.resultCategories.vars.prototype)|e 
   }}">
    {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
    {% for ResultCategory in form.resultCategories %}
        <li>{{ form_row(ResultCategory.category) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>

</ul>        
{{ form_rest(form) }}{# form.items's prototype is rendered twice #}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
<input type="submit" value ="add" />
</form> 

 {% block javascripts %}


<script type="text/javascript">
// Get the div that holds the collection of tags
var collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');

 // setup an "add a tag" link
   var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>');
  var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

$addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
    e.preventDefault();

    // add a new tag form (see next code block)
    addTagForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
   });
 });
  // Get the div that holds the collection of tags
 var collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');

  // setup an "add a tag" link
 var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>');
 var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
  collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

 $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
    e.preventDefault();

    // add a new tag form (see next code block)
    addTagForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
   });
  });

  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection of forms is not rendered since you don't initiate it! [See the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). There are "dummy" tags object used to create the tag forms.

Comment: The aim is to show a "TagType" form for each tag you wanna add! If you don't pass a tag object when you create the form, then no form is rendered! You can use the "add" button to create a new tag form at runtime by using the prototype

Comment: Try to create a Tag object and to add it to the Category object before to pass the Category object to the FormBuilder

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access private property Ladela\OdeskTesterBundle\Entity\ResultCategory::$category

Comment: Does it happen on form submit or on form creation?

Comment: Well, no... don't do it! You are changing your question!

Comment: Well, you cannot call $tag->category! Why don't you use setter functions? E.g. $tag->setCategory($category); Moreover, I don't undestand why you designed the tags such as the category has to be set! You should tag a category, not vice versa. I expect something like $category->addTag($tag).

Comment: @Sergios.Soft If you have another question, please ask it. This comment thread is getting rather long.

Comment: i should Tag a resultCategory from category :) becouse in category i gave collection :) , this is my logical way

Comment: look at my forms , i cannot manage to do this :( don't figure out